# Calculating an integral modified Bessel function with singularity

Tags: integration, bessel-functions, singularity

I'm looking to numerically solve a definite integral involving the modified Bessel function of the second kind, $$\int_{0}^{r}K_0 (r)G(r)r\,dr.$$
The problem is that $K_0$ has a singularity at $r=0$.
I saw someplace that it's possible to change the boundary of this integral, but I don't understand why it works:
$$\int_{0}^{r}K_0 (r)G(r)r\,dr=-\int_{r}^{\infty} K_0 (r)G(r)r\,dr.$$

Comment: Endpoint singularities of that type are no problem, as long as the integrand is sufficiently regular inside the interval of integration. That would depend on $G$, naturally.

Comment: Do you want to compute an integral, or solve an equation? Which equation is that? And what is an equation "in a point"?

Comment: how I can numerically compute this integral, I have a problem with the value of the function in point r=0

Comment: And where is the problem? The singularity isn't one, as I said. $G$ may be one, but as long as you keep it secret, it's hard to tell.

Comment: $G$ is a good function, I don't have a problem with it, but $K_0(0)=\infty$, so I can't compute integral in $r=0$

Comment: Near $r=0$, $r K_0(r)$ behaves like $-r\log r$. Note that $-r \log r \to 0$ as $r \to 0+$.

Comment: I see it, but still how I can compute my integral